# Toggle button doesnt react with useContext

Tags: react-native, use-context

Im trying to toggle my navbar button using useContext but nothing is happening.
I created a ButtonContext file and declare a isPressed variable.
In App.tsx i create with useCallBack that do toggle isPressed when active.

App.tsx:

```
const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
const toggleButton = useCallback(()=>{
    setIsPressed(!isPressed);
},[]);

const contextValue = {
    isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
    login: login,
    logout: logout,
    isPressed: isPressed,
    toggleButton: toggleButton
}
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
        // Value will listening for isLoggedIn state changes
        value={contextValue}>
        <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Home/>
```

ButtonContext.tsx:

```
export const ToggleButton = createContext({
isPressed:false,
toggleButton: ()=>{}
})
```

LoginBar.tsx:

```
import {ToggleButton} from "../../../shared/context/ButtonContext";

const LoginBar: React.FC = () => {

const hamburgerButton = useContext(ToggleButton);
const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

const [pressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div className="toggle-button">
            <span className="bar"> </span>
            <span className="bar"> </span>
            <span className="bar"> </span>
        </div>
        {hamburgerButton.isPressed && <MobileNavbar/>}
        {!hamburgerButton.isPressed && <div
            className={hamburgerButton.isPressed ? 'mobile-navbar' : 'login-bar'}>
            <ul>
                {!auth.isLoggedIn && <li><HeaderBtn btnName="Login" route="/login"/> 
              </li>}
                {auth.isLoggedIn && <li><HeaderBtn btnName="My cart" route="/cart"/> 
              </li>}
                {auth.isLoggedIn && <li><HeaderBtn btnName="Logout" route="/"/></li>}
            </ul>
        </div>}

    </React.Fragment>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add `isPressed` in the array

```
const toggleButton = useCallback(()=>{
    setIsPressed(!isPressed);
},[isPressed]);
```

You need to access the context like this:

```
const {toggleButton} = useContext(AuthContext);
```

And to change the value you have to call `toggleButton()`.

Comment: Thanks alot but still didnt solve the problem.

Comment: And how ill access the isPressed variable if i do {toggleButton}? Im pretty new at React so im sorry that i dont get it

Comment: You could access isPressed by   `const {isPressed} = useContext(AuthContext);`

I have created an react sample https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-3q3fe?file=/Login.js.